# submit handler is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I tried working with Jquery and I need to pass the values of the form on submission using Submit handler which is not working. I am new to Jquery and don't know what went wrong. Following is my Javascript code

```
$('document').ready(function() {


  jQuery.validator.addMethod('minStrict', function(value, el, param) {
    if (value == '') {
      return true;
    }
    return value >= param;
  });

  $.validator.addMethod('reqStrict', function(value, el, param) {
    alert(value);
    alert(el.id);
    alert(value == '');
    return value.length >= param;
  });


  $('#form1').validate({
    rules: {
      keyword1: {
        reqStrict: 1
      },

      MinPrice: {
        minStrict: 0,
        number: true
      },
      MaxPrice: {
        minStrict: function(element) {
          return $("#MinPrice").val() > 0 ? $("#MinPrice").val() : 0;
        },
        number: true
      },
      MaxHandlingTime: {
        minStrict: 1,
        digit: true,
      }

    },
    messages: {
      keyword1: "Please enter a keyword",
      MinPrice: {
        minStrict: "Minimum price cannot be below 0",
        number: "Price should be a valid number "
      },
      MaxPrice: {
        minStrict: "Maximum price cannot be less than minimum price or below 0",
        number: "Price should be a valid number "
      },
      MaxHandlingTime: {
        digit: "Max Handling time should be a valid digit",
        minStrict: "Max Handling time should be greater than or equal to 1"
      }

    },
    highlight: function(element) {
      $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
      $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'help-block',
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      if (element.parent('.input-group').length) {
        error.insertAfter(element.parent());
      } else {
        error.insertAfter(element);
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function() {
      alert("Hey babe");
    }
  });
});
```

Could you please tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: Any errors in the console? What validation plugin are you using?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: If u are going to use code from the internet, might be better to start with something simpler.